# Objective C Posing vs. Polymorphism / Method Overrriding

Tags: ios, objective-c, macos

Upon learning more about posing in Objective C, I couldn't help but wonder where the distinction lies between posing and polymorphism, a concept used in many other programming languages.

It is my understanding that posing is used at runtime to intercept a pre-existing class vs polymorphism allows devs to redefine methods.

Is the difference between these two concepts that posing is used at a class level and at runtime in order to intercept an existing class vs polymorphism is used strictly for redefining methods, or is there some overlap between the two?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Polymorphism preserves the inheritance hierarchy whereas posing does not.

Posing changes the behavior of existing classes universally within the application.

Polymorphism allows you to modify the behavior of a class within the subclass, but that new behavior will only be present when an instance of your subclass is created.

Polymorphism is at the core of OO design and is a pervasive and common pattern throughout OO systems.

Posing creates exceptional fragility, has a high maintenance cost over time and should be avoided in all but the most extreme situations.

Comment: Great answer, very clear now to me what the differences are. Thank you!